# Need help for passing data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

In the code, there is a StatefulWidget 'SpectatorPage' and I want the page to see all of the widget methods 'chatScreenContainer' of the StatefulWidgets 'ChatPage'.
And I also want that the SpectatorPage to see the rebuild of the 'chatScreenContainer' when 'ChatPage' decides to rebuild.
Here is my code :

```
class SpectatorPage extends StatefulWidget {

  Game game;
  SpectatorPage(Key? key,this.game) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SpectatorPage> createState() => SpectatorPageState();
}

class SpectatorPageState extends State<SpectatorPage> {

  List<ChatPage> runningMatches = [];

  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2
          ),
          itemCount: widget.game.players.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              child: runningMatches[index],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then, the 'ChatPage' :

```
class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // Player p1;
  // Player p2;

  // ChatPage(this.p1, this.p2);

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => ChatPageState();
}

class ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {

  bool isYourTurn = Random().nextBool();
  List<String> messages_stack = [];
  List<Widget> widget_stack = [];

  List<String> current_props = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    super.initState();
    sendMessage('Salut ça va ?');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> propositions = []; // generateProposition();
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 131, 166),
      child: Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 131, 166),
        width: 1000,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 36.0),
            chatScreenContainer(),
            SizedBox(height: 4.0),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              ),
              width: 340,
              height: 40,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 131, 166),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    width: 160,
                    height: 16,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0, left: 6.0),
                      child: Text('...', style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 2, 80),fontSize: 10.0, decoration: TextDecoration.none),),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 42.0)),
                  Container(
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                content: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                        }); 
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.lightbulb, color: Colors.yellow, size: 16),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 8.0,
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 131, 166),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Container(
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white, size: 16,),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 8.0,
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 131, 166), // <-- Button color
                        
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 22.0),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              ),
              width: 360,
              height: 220,
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget chatScreenContainer() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        width: 400,
        height: 460,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 360,
              height: 440,
              child: Container(
                /* child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget_stack.length,
                  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    return widget_stack[index];
                  })
                ), */
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this method to your "SpectatorPageState"

```
 reload (){
    ChatPage(reload:reload);
    if(mounted){
      setState(() {
      });
    }
  }
```

add this to your declaration of "ChatPage"

```
  const ChatPage({Key? key,this.reload ,}) : super(key: key);
 final Function()? reload;
  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => ChatPageState();
}
```

When you initialise yours "ChatPage" in runningMatches

```
runningMatches.add(ChatPage(reload:reload));
```

When you need to reload in "ChatPage"

```
if(widget.reload != null ){
widget.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

But I forgot to mention, I have another class that use the ChatPage constructor
My question is, now what do I put in the constructors of this class ?
class GamePipe extends StatefulWidget {

  override
  State<GamePipe> createState() => GamePipeState();

}

class GamePipeState extends State<GamePipe> {

  Widget currentPage = ChatPage();

  List<Widget> differentPages = [
    
    ChatPage(),
  ];

  override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return currentPage;
  }
}

Comment: Also, How do I access the 'chatScreenContainer' method from the SpectatorPageState class

Comment: i edit my anwser.
chatScreenContainer is a method so you only need to add the file path to your SpectatorPageState file